# Shortcircuit Operator Evaluation order

Tags: c, operator-precedence

```
main()
{
int a,b=0,c=1,d=1;
a=++b&&++c||++d;    
printf("%d %d %d",b,c,d);  //1 2 1
b=0,c=1,d=1;
a=b&&++c||++d;
printf("%d %d %d",b,c,d);  //0 1 2
}
```

Why second printf gives answer 0 1 2 instead of 0 2 1 ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with "assignment precedence" and all to do with short circuit evaluation.

Comment: Changing the title won't change the answer... your answer ***is*** the answer, the fact that you haven't marked it as accepted suggests you don't know what short-circuit evaluation actually means, though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why second printf gives answer 0 1 2 instead of 0 2 1 ?

`&&` is [short-circuiting.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

In

```
a=b&&++c||++d;
```

`++c` will not be evaluated if `b` is `0` which is the case here. Hence `c` is `1` instead of `2`.